# PHP: load set of properties (from config files) only ONCE for all user requests

Tags: php, include, config, configuration-files

I have a file which contains application specific properties (e.g. timeouts etc.) which I have placed in a `my_app.ini` properties file and which I read using `parse_ini_file()`.

**How/where should I make this code run exactly once for all my user requests (I do not want my application to read the `.ini` file on every request) ?**

I though of putting the config file reading code in a separate PHP and including this with `include_once`/`require_once` in all pages that require access to the config variables.  But:

1. Will this mean that the file will be
   read once for every different page
   (so different times since I have
   multiple pages with
   `require_once('config_setup.php')`)
   ?
2. Is `require_once`/`include_once`
       executed only once across all user
       requests ?

I am interested in possibly hearing other (better) ways how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP doesn't keep state between multiple requests. This means that standalone PHP cannot store variables in memory between requests. Sessions are saved to disk (by default), config files needs to be reparsed, etc.

You can however use extensions such as [APC](http://php.net/apc) or [Memcache](http://php.net/memcache)/[Memcached](http://php.net/memcached) to store variables in memory. These extensions needs to be compiled/installed on the server so that their functions are available.

Parsing your INI will not be a bottleneck for your application. For simplicity's sake, it's easier just to parse it everytime. That 0.00001 ms you'll be saving otherwise isn't worth it.

---

[`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once) and [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) has nothing to do with persistance. It just tells PHP to only include the script *if it wasn't already included during this request*.

Comment: There is an overhead to parsing the .ini file every time, profiling will tell you exactly how high. I've often put the pre-parsed variable object/array into APC (inside the PHP process, unlike Memcache) and it is easy, and fast.

Comment: @Alister: It's easy and fast if your host offers you APC support or if you have control over your server's configuration and you are not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

include/require_once mean that the file will only be loaded once during the processing of a single request; however, whenever a new request is received, it will be read again as the script is parsed.

In addition, for what you want to do here, you would have to read the configuration and place its value in the session; then, if the specific key you use in the session array is defined, you do not need to reparse the file:

```
if ( !array_key_exists( 'config' , $_SESSION ) ) {
    $_SESSION['config'] = parse_ini_file ( 'whatever.ini' );
}
```

However, this approach has a major disadvantage - if the configuration file changes, users that are already on the site will keep on using the previous version of the file.

Comment: The major problem with this approach is that the same config file is going to be read once for each user session.  I do not want that - I want to load it once for the whole web application (pretty much like the Application scope in JSP)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, reading the `*.ini` is hardly going to be the bottleneck of any service in normal circumstances, so really think whether the advantages you seek (which are...?) outweigh the disadvantages. I have no problem scanning INI files, although I usually use native PHP to do some settings as long as no non-PHP programmer needs to reach them. Of course, people are now going to advocate key/value stores like APC & Memcached because of the persistence issue, but that will only be an advantage if your file is (relatively) huge for an ini file, otherwise it's just overhead if you don't use it already.

The only way I know how to get a (scalar) setting across requests without extensions in Apache easily is to do some `SetEnv` business in the host configuration (so scalar values are just read from the environment), but those are kludgy at best, and require a server reload or restart to pick up alterations.

Stay with the ini file, or possibly with a straight PHP file with settings, in which case APC could grant you a small advantage by caching the file until it changes.